# How to write nested bson.M{} correctly

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, mongo-go

Suppose we have the following struct:

```
type shop struct {
   ID primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
   Brands *brand         `json:"brand,omitempty" bson:"brand,omitempty"`
}

type brand struct {
  ID primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"deploymentid,omitempty"`
}
```

I tried to find a document using `findOne()` but I don't get any document even there is a result match by using the MongoDB shell.

```
filter := bson.M{"brand" : bson.M{"_id" : someValue}}
var shopWithBrand shop
mycollection.findOne(ctx , filter).Decode(&shopWithBrand)
```

What mistake did I make?

Comment: Your struct tags are completely invalid, and [won't even compile](https://play.golang.org/p/4rQ2Q-ge-WS).

Answer (score 1):

This filter:

```
filter := bson.M{"brand" : bson.M{"_id" : someValue}}
```

Tells you want documents that have a `brand` field that is an embedded document **having a single `_id` field** whose value is the value of `someValue`.

This would actually work if your embedded documents would only consist of this single `_id` field, but your embedded `brand` has this ID field mapped to `deploymentid` and most likely has other fields as well (which you "stripped off" to minimize the example), and that is why it won't match.

Instead you want documents that have a `brand` field being a document that has a matching `deployment` field *among other fields*. This is how you can express that:

```
filter := bson.M{"brand.deploymentid" : someValue}
```

Comment: I thought I don't have to specify values of other fields as well , brand.deploymentid  works thank you :)